# Issue on Adding Values to a Variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/7UQnN/1/) and let me know why I am not able to add values to the `var result` variable in my code? I think I declared the result in a global scope so all methods will have access to it but it is not functioning here for me!

Here is the code I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="25" />25</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="50" />50</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="75" />75</li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = 0;
    $("#25").on("click", function () {
        var newResult = result + 25;
        $("#result").html(newResult);
    });
    $("#50").on("click", function () {
        var newResult = result + 50;
        $("#result").html(newResult);
    });
    $("#75").on("click", function () {
        var newResult = result + 75;
        $("#result").html(newResult);
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First jQuery is not added in the fiddle
- You are not updating the value of result when an item is selected

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = 0;
    $("#25, #50, #75").on("change", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            result += +this.id;
        } else {
            result -= +this.id;
        }
        $("#result").html(result);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BD6zg/)

Comment: Thanks Arun , but can you please let me know what does "+this" mean in your code? I mean adding the plus sign before "this"?

Comment: @Behseini it is the unary plus operator, I used it to convert the string id to an int value(used it instead of `parseInt(this.id)`)

Comment: Thanks but the solution is not working on this Example http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/q9V35/4/ ! can you please take alook at that and let me know what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: @Behseini look at your console there are no variables named `newval` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q9V35/5/